# Breaking D3 in separate HTML, JS and CSS files not working

Tags: javascript, html, css, d3.js, svg

Most `D3` examples have the `HTML`, `JavaScript` and `CSS` all in the same file. Using this example http://bl.ocks.org/d3noob/5028304, I am trying to break these into separate files (this way I'll be able to embed D3 into a website, putting the files in the proper locations).

When all in one file, let's say `index.html`, everything works as it should. When I separate this into 3 files: `index.html`, `sankey_create.js`, and `style.css`, The `HTML` title (that I inserted `<h1>Title</h1>`) renders, but the SVG doesn't.

**Possible Issue #1: File Referencing**

Everything is in one folder and I think that I have referenced the separate files correctly in the `header` (The `console` in `Firefox` says that all the files have loaded):

```
<script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
<script src="sankey.js"></script>
<script src="sankey_create.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
```

**Possible Issue #2: Binding to External `HTML` Element**

The way this example works is that there is a `<p id="chart">` element to which the `D3` `SVG` binds to:

```
var svg = d3.select("#chart").append("svg") // This line is in sankey_create.js
```

I'm not sure if I need to reference the element differently now that they are in separate files.

I have only included the code that I think maybe causing the issue since, but Ican provide more code/information if necessary.

Comment: Did you put the `p` elememt (`<p id="chart">`) in the body of the host index.html document?

Comment: yes i do that in the body

Comment: Ok, well, there is no special thing that needs to be done due to the seperate files. Semantically the script tags are replaced by the code they reference and the referenced code is executed before the next node is processed, so it's the same as having the code in your index file.

Comment: @Cool Blue: You, sir, answered my question! I had all the script references in the header, so I was actually trying to bind to the `<p>` element before I created it. I put the script after the `<p>` and it worked. If you post that as an answer, I will give you credit.

Comment: Good for you mate. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To analyse the problem you need to understand that semantically, the script tags can be replaced by the code they reference and the referenced code is executed before the next node is processed, so it's the same as having the code in your index file at the point where the script tags are.